# Jenkins: \Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin"" was unexpected at this time

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I have a Jenkins controller and several agent nodes. Some jobs running on Windows give me this error message:

```
\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\jre\bin"" was unexpected at this time.
```

These jobs run without problems on a Windows system itself, but not when running them within Jenkins. So I looked a little bit deeper and found out, that in the node information, I can see this value for `java.library.path` under `jenkinsserver/computer/node/systemInfo` (as an example):

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
C:\Users\bsadmin\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin";.
```

I think, this error comes from the last part: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_172\bin"`. I see this on every windows agent machine.

Where does this value come from? Is it possible, to disable it somehow?

**EDIT**

Here is a picture of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I'm also dealing with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think Java differs between Jenkins Master and Slave.
For example, PC of Jenkins Master is x64 but slave is x86.

Comment: I put the same versions of java (both x64 and version 1.8.0_212) on master and slave and everything works well. Thanks for this tip =D

Answer (score 0):

The issue started at my CI system after I upgrade the Java version on my Jenkins node to latest x86. (the node was working well before)
To resolve it I uninstalled the x86 version and installed x64 Java version.

Thanks.